How to detect whether each element of a list of element-nodes does feature a specific css-class name?
Given the following test environment ...


const nodeList = document.querySelectorAll('p');
const testArray = Array.from(nodeList);

testArray.every(function (elmNode) {
  if (elmNode.classList.contains('ipsum')) {

    console.log(
      'All element nodes do feature the `ipsum` css-class name.'
    );
  }
});
.lorem {
  font-family: courier new, courier;
}
<p class="lorem ipsum">Lorem ipsum</p>
<p class="lorem dolor sit">dolor sit</p>
<p class="lorem amet">amet.</p>



... the above implementation does not log the correct result.
How can one detect whether each element of a list of element-nodes does feature a specific css-class name?
And as for the above example code, how would one execute an additional function in case the condition (every element node features a specific class-name) is met?

Remove that if and the alert. Just return v.classList.contains('hohlipidrili')

I need it with the condition IF all are filled, only then.
Not return

The callback function that you pass to every needs to return a value, not make alerts. Make the callback function body return v.classList.contains('hohlipidrili');, nothing else. Whether all items were a match or not, you determine afterwards, by looking at what the whole jaJivuSrediHohlichertei.every(...) thing itself returned, that will either be true or false.

I need to execute a function under this condition, alert for example. that is, if all items have this class, only then execute the function. How!?

See my appended, previous comment.

if (myarray.every(v => v.classList.contains('foo'))) ...

if (myarray.every(v => v.matches(".foo"))) even better using matches

The callback function used in the .every(...) prototype function should return a boolean value. If you want to perform an operation based on whether all elements contain a value or meet a certain class condition, you should act according to the result of the .every(...) function
let jaJivuSrediHohlochertei = Array.from(test)

let isHaveClass = jaJivuSrediHohlichertei.every(function(v){
    return v.classList.contains('hohlipidrili');
})

if(isHaveClass){
    alert('all itemts has this class')
}


I tried it like this, it doesn't work. Thank you, let's try your version now.https://www.facebook.com/share/8i1DoqPkP95hY9Li/

does not work. when you add a class to an array and when all the items in the array receive the added class, nothing happens

If the alert(...) function is not working, it means that at least one of the elements in the jaJivuSrediHohlichertei array does not contain the 'hohlipidrili' class. Make sure they all contain it and try again.

rechecked. alert is triggered, but if you try to remove the class from the last element of the function. test.lastElementChild.classList.remove('hohlipidrili').

you don't know how to delete the class in the last element after executing this function

Since test is an array, you can't access the last element by using lastElementChild. Here, you need to access the last element by using test.at(-1) or test[test.length-1] and perform the deletion based on it. So, if all elements contain the class, the following code should work: test[test.length-1].classList.remove(...).

One firstly should consult a reliable documentation/reference like MDN on the every array method.
Secondly, one might write a test case, boiled down to the most necessary scenario/environment, not only for a well asked question on Stackoverflow, but utmost for ones own (debugging) sake.
As already stated, the every method expects a callback function which has to return a boolean (or a truthy/falsy) value.
The OP's edited example code then changes to ...


function proceed() {
  console.log(
    '... proceed with next task ...'
  );
}
function doesElementFeatureIpsumClass(elmNode) {
  return elmNode.classList.contains('ipsum');
}
function doesElementFeatureLoremClass(elmNode) {
  return elmNode.classList.contains('lorem');
}
const nodeList = document.querySelectorAll('p');

if (
  Array
    .from(nodeList)
    .every(doesElementFeatureIpsumClass)
) {

  proceed();

} else {
  console.log(
    'Not every element node does feature the `ipsum` css class-name.'
  );
}

if ([...nodeList].every(doesElementFeatureLoremClass)) {

  console.log(
    'Every element node does feature the `lorem` css class-name.'
  );
  proceed();
}
.lorem {
  font-family: courier new, courier;
}
<p class="lorem ipsum">Lorem ipsum</p>
<p class="lorem dolor sit">dolor sit</p>
<p class="lorem amet">amet.</p>



Following the OP's comment ...

I repeat the question again: after checking, if all the elements have a "test" class, delete the "test" class in the last element. What does this have to do with it!? and delete the "test" class in the last element only if

... the example code easily changes to ...


const nodeArray = [...document.querySelectorAll('p')];

if (
  nodeArray.every(node => node.classList.contains('lorem'))
) {
  nodeArray.at(-1).classList.remove('lorem');
}
.lorem {
  font-family: courier new, courier;
  color: #c0f;
}
<p class="lorem ipsum">Lorem ipsum</p>
<p class="lorem dolor sit">dolor sit</p>
<p class="lorem amet">amet.</p>




I repeat the question again: after checking, if all the elements have a "test" class, delete the "test" class in the last element. What does this have to do with it!? and delete the "test" class in the last element only if

@ВиталийЮрко ... The requirement of your latest comment was never part of your original question, nor was it part of the comments below the latter. Please fell free editing and updating your original post to your latest requirement/s.

if (
Array
.from(nodeList)
.every(doesElementFeatureIpsumClass)
) {. const test =nodeList[nodeList.length -1]; test.classList.contains("addclass") } dont work...

@ВиталийЮрко ... I'm aware, that you're not a native English speaker, neither am I. Therefore it is even more important to precisely formulate sentences in your mother language first and then try to translate it as best as possible. From everything you did produce today I doubt that you're spending too much effort with the very first task. Thus, I don't exactly know, what you want to tell with your last cryptic comment. Please consider taking your time for a good problem description, if you're further interested in people responding to you.

after checking the entire array, whether all the elements have THIS "test" class in the array, delete the class of THIS "test" class in the last element of this array. similarly, add

The example codes, explanations, and the documentation link given to you with the above answer provides you with everything that's needed in order to solve the problem. Please do not comment anymore under this answer. If there are other problems that could not be solved with the already provided answers, please edit your original post accordingly. In case other requirements are too different from the original problem/question you are expected to open another questions with a good description and a minimal reproducible example.

Wt about add class back. Thnks

@ВиталийЮрко ... are you aware of the methods of an element node's  classList property ?.. e.g. ... contains, add, remove, ... thus, regarding yours ...  "Wt about add class back" ... nodeArray.at(-1).classList.add('lorem');

the option is not working. writes: "at is not a function"

@ВиталийЮрко ... For the last time ... it is hard for people that try to be helpful to constantly guess occurring issues from cryptic half sentences. Please open, as already suggested, a new question with a precise description of the current problem and a minimal reproducible example.

your option does not work, I went through the code, I did not like the inscription not found when deleting the class. Your option gives the error "at" - this is not a function

minimal reproducible example если честно, я ебу что там написано :D

why create a new topic if the question concerns this topic, and then return to this question

@ВиталийЮрко ... You are at any point also free to edit your original post describing exactly which problems still occur despite all the provided solutions. You have to make the effort, otherwise nobody really can help you any further. until now literally nothing of any substance has been provided by yourself in order to solve your problem.

Okey...........
